# How to change tensorflow loss function from single number to an array

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss-function

I am working with Tensorflow's DNNRegressor module to train a 2 hidden layered neural network with 100 nodes each in order to map an input layer containing 9 parameters and an output layer containing 3980 parameters.

The size of my training set is approximately 500,000 data points. So far, I have achieved some success in training this neural network. I work with the default loss function, which is the Mean Squared Error. This is a single floating point variable, and I would like to have a loss function that has the same size as the output layer - 3980 floating values (because the output layer is a spectrum of light).

Has anyone considered/dealt with such a situation?

Comment: Loss values are, by definition, scalar. It represents the one goal you are trying to minimize. If you have a vector of loss values, which one is the one that you would try to minimize?

Comment: You're correct when you say this. But I just don't understand how one value is enough to optimise a neural network that predicts multiple values. In my case, its a spectrum of light, and there can be specific wavelengths that are more important to my use - if I can optimise the neural network in a manner that ensures that specific wavelengths are given a higher priority, it would be really amazing.

Comment: I see what you mean. Typically in such case you have a scalar value that aggregates the losses for all classes. What what you mention is a common use case, and typically what one does is giving different "weights" to examples with a class where you want the network to "put more effort". Losses in `tf.loss` usually offer a `weight` parameter for this (e.g. [`tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy)).